# jQuery Ajax stop long polling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ping

I wrote a ping html version, which is appears in a jQuery dialog box.

I wish that when I close the dialog box, then stop the ping.

But in my version alert the 'close' message, and again continues the ping.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var init = 1;
  var timestamp = null;
  var tag = $("<div></div>");
  function waitForMsg() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/modules/ping2.php?host=localhost&tsp="+timestamp+"&init="+init,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        var json = eval('('+data+ ')');
        var str = json['out'].replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
        tag.html(str).dialog({
          title: 'Ping',
          modal: false,
          width: 480,
          height: 550,
          close: function() {
            alert('close');
          }
        }).dialog('open');
        timestamp = json["tsp"];
        init = 0;
        setTimeout("waitForMsg()", 1000);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error: "+textStatus + " "+ errorThrown);
        setTimeout("waitForMsg()", 15000);
      }
    });
  }
  $(function() {
    $("#button").on('click', function() {
      waitForMsg();
    });
  });
</script>
```

How do i cancel the polling?

Comment: assign the timeout to a global variable and make use of clearTimeout ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i pointed out in my comment :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var timeout; // this is a variable the timout will be assigned to
  var init = 1;
  var timestamp = null;
  var tag = $("<div></div>");
  function waitForMsg() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/modules/ping2.php?host=localhost&tsp="+timestamp+"&init="+init,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        var json = eval('('+data+ ')');
        var str = json['out'].replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
        tag.html(str).dialog({
          title: 'Ping',
          modal: false,
          width: 480,
          height: 550,
          close: function() {
            alert('close');
            clearTimeout(timeout); // here we clear the timeout
          }
        }).dialog('open');
        timestamp = json["tsp"];
        init = 0;
        timeout = setTimeout("waitForMsg()", 1000); // here we assign the timout
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error: "+textStatus + " "+ errorThrown);
        setTimeout("waitForMsg()", 15000);
      }
    });
  }
  $(function() {
    $("#button").on('click', function() {
      waitForMsg();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi John, your suggestion is work (the dialog box does not reappear), however the polling is in progress in the background.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop an ajax request early, store the ajax request in a variable:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    /* ajax params */
});
```

And you can abort the request when you need to like this:

```
request.abort();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. The dialog box disappears but again appears when it get new ping result from the web server.